# Asking a specific question from a general one

Tags: simulation

## Setting

I have data about a board game which has been played multiple times with different players per game (though players reoccur in all kinds of different constellations). During the game one can score points in one of seven categories. The general question is: What is the best strategy? On what category should players concentrate?

## Details about the data and performed transformations

The original data has the variables:

- game - the number of the game
- name - the name of the player
- military points
- money points
- world wonder points
- ... points
- sum of points

which I transferred into

- game
- name
- sum of points (a little repetitive, since its the same for a game and name)
- place in game (a little repetitive, since its the same for a game and name)
- type of points (one of the seven categories)
- number of points
- percentage this type of points contributed to the total amount of points of this player for this game

## My Question

Asking the right question is been said to be the most important thing in Data Science and in most situations I managed to find a good concrete (programmable) question, but this one seems tough to me.

So: **How do I ask a specific question to answer the general question?**

Of course I have already asked/answered simple questions regarding the winning players of each game. For example: "What is the type of points that contributes most to the total points for winning players (whose success proved them right)?"

Now I'd like to make analyses over the entire field of players.

An even more advanced question would consider that player reoccur across games.

---

*I have no idea what tag to use here.*

Comment: Do you have stats only for the end of the game, or do you have them on any type of regular interval?  For many games, your lead 'accelerates' as you amass an advantage over your opponents.

Comment: @j.a.gartner: No, I only have the mentioned data from the end of the games. Its a board game, so it is difficult to get additional data. I have to make due with what I have.